Weird Issue on VBA Macro On Pivot Table
I'm modifying an existing code that I've asked here(it was created by a user here) with a very weird issue.
Code is as follows:
Sub Pivot()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim ptField As PivotField
    Dim ptRange As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim lastCol As Long
    
    ' Set the worksheet where you want to create the pivot table
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2") ' Change "Sheet1" to your sheet name
    ws.Cells.Clear
    ' Define the data range for the pivot table
    Dim sheet_from As Worksheet
    Set sheet_from = Sheets("Upload")
    last_row = sheet_from.Range("A65336").End(xlUp).Row
    Set ptRange = sheet_from.Range("A2:BJ" & last_row)
    
    ' Create a pivot table on a new sheet or existing sheet
    Set pt = ws.Parent.PivotTableWizard(TableDestination:=ws.Range("A1"), _
                                         TableName:="PivotTable1")
    
    ' Add fields to the pivot table
    With pt
        ' Add fields to rows
        
        Set ptField = .PivotFields("Narrative1")
        ptField.Orientation = xlRowField
        
        ' Add fields to values
        Set ptField = .PivotFields("Column1") ' Change "Amount" to your field name
        ptField.Orientation = xlDataField
        ptField.Function = xlSum ' You can change the function as needed (e.g., xlCount, xlAverage, etc.)
        
        
         With .DataPivotField
            .Orientation = xlColumnField
            .Position = 1
        End With
    End With
    sheet_from.Activate
End Sub

Issue is as the following. On the original file reference(Upload) data is fine, when I make it a pivot table, it pulls through number that doesn't exist, for example:
`
Notice that the number is number with 4 words, yet it doesn't exist in the original upload file, only 5 and 6 letters. This issue is making me crazy, any tips would be appreciate.
Thanks
I tried checking the original upload macro, but the numbers match. Just in case this is the code
Sub Upload()
    Dim FileToOpen As Variant
    Dim Openbook As Workbook
    Dim UploadSheet As Worksheet
    Dim SourceRange As Range
    Dim DestRange As Range
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    Set UploadSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Upload")
    
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        Set Openbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
        Set SourceRange = Openbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange
        Set DestRange = UploadSheet.Range("A1").Resize(SourceRange.Rows.Count, SourceRange.Columns.Count)
        DestRange.Value = SourceRange.Value
        Openbook.Close False
    End If
    
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

The pivot table shows error on orientation property, but I dont think that is the issue`
